# Metis: how to use and tutorial recommendation

Tags: finite-element, c++, mesh-generation, domain-decomposition, partitioning

I am new to METIS and trying to use it in my fortran code. I read the manual online. But still, I am not sure about how to implement it my code. I tried the test cases in the graphs directory. For example, I partitioned the 2d mesh `metis.mesh` by using `mpmetis -gtype=nodal metis.mesh 4`. And it gave me two output files:`metis.mesh.npart.4` and `metis.mesh.epart.4`. I opened these files, they are point values that make no sense to me. How can I visualize the partition results? And is there any good tutorial about metis that can help me to start? Thank you!